# How to install netcdf-fortran on Ubuntu

Tags: gfortran, netcdf

I am using a Fortran software which needs for compilation `gfortran` and `netcdf-fortran.`

As working environment I have `WSL` with `Ubuntu 20.04.4` on Windows 10
and `gfortran 9.4.0`.

After some search I found a description how to build the netcdf Fortran libraries:

```
https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/current/building_netcdf_fortran.html
```

I downloaded the latest netcdf c release at:

```
git clone http://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c netcdf-c
```

Then I downloaded the latest betcdf-fortran release:

```
git clone https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-fortran.git netcdf-fortran
```

How can I compile/build the newest netcdf-Fortran library having download the netcdf-c and netcdf-fortran projects?

Comment: The README of the project contains the text "To install this package, please see the document: https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/current/building_netcdf_fortran.html". Having read that document, which parts of the installation process do you not understand?

Comment: Alternatively you could just use conda. `conda create -n mynewnev -c conda-forge netcdf4 netcdf-fortran` should get you there.

Comment: Instead of installing netcdf-bin, you should install libnetcdff-dev to get the Fortran libraries.

Comment: sudo apt install libnetcdff-dev solved my question.